# Xampp Apache connection very unstable

Tags: apache, xampp

I'm having a bit of trouble with Xampp. Apache keeps stopping and starting again every time I try to load a page. It changes ports and PID's every second and in the end, I'm lucky if the page loads at all. I have no idea what causes this, it wasn't doing that a few hours ago, and I didn't touch Xampp or Apache's configuration. I tried reinstalling xampp but the problem remains.

Skype isn't on, I know that's not the problem.